Thread lambda capture loop variable
Is this safe to capture a temporary variable in a thread function?
std::vector<std::string> adapterList = getAdapterList();
std::vector<std::thread> captureThreads;

for (auto adapterName : adapterList) {
    captureThreads.push_back(std::thread([&] {
        // do something with adapterName. Safe?
    }));
}

for (auto& thread : captureThreads) {
    if (thread.joinable())
        thread.join();
}


The variable adapterName will be local inside the loop, you can't capture it by reference. Capture it by value instead.

No.  adapterName is a new object each iteration.

You could use for (auto& adapterName : adapterList) instead to get it to be safe

Unrelated: Change push_back(std::thread([&] ... to emplace_back([&] ... to not create an unnecessary std::thread that is moved into the vector.

@TedLyngmo good point. Added a side note to my answer about it.

It's not safe to capture adapterName by reference (as you attempted) because this line:
for (auto adapterName : adapterList) {

Means adapterName is a copy of the current element in adapterList. The scope of this copy is only inside the loop iteration. Therefore when the thread will execute it can become a dangling refernce.
You can fix it in one of the 2 ways below:

Capture it by value:
//------------------------------------V---
captureThreads.push_back(std::thread([=] {



or:

Change the loop to get a reference to the element:
//--------V-----------------------------
for (auto & adapterName : adapterList) {



Note that the 2nd way is more efficient as it saves copies. But it relies on the fact (which holds in your case) that the adapterList vector stays alive as long as the threads execute, and therefore the reference to the element stays valid.
A side note:
You can use std::vector::emplace_back instead of push_back to avoid the move of the temporary std::thread into the vector (and create it inside the vector directly instead).

Definitely not, in this case. You are capturing by reference, while your adapterName is a copy, so it's going away after each loop iteration.
Make the adapterName a reference and you should be fine, since your adapterList remains alive and unchanged while your threads are running.
Note: in C++, a "reference to a reference" doesn't exist, so capturing a reference by reference will just be a reference to the same object. Can you make a sentence with more instances of the word "reference"?
